# Adding a mysql user store with custom schema to WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: mysql, wso2-identity-server

Currently, trying to use WSO2 Identity Server to authenticate users from a mysql user store that I created with my own schema. However, whenever I add this user store as a secondary one in WSO2, the users do not appear on the management console.

And when I attempt to authenticate a user from that store I get the error message:

```
[2019-05-24 10:01:15,951] ERROR{org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.impl.BasicAuthenticationHandler} 
-  Error occurred while trying to authenticate,
Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION
```

Comment: regarding 'created with my own schema' have you customized the schema provided in the IS pack.

Comment: @senthalan By 'created with my own schema' I mean that I have a pre-existing mysql user store with username and password fields. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user stores of the WSO2 servers need to have the specific schema (the schema script located in the dbscripts folder). You need to import users using [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Users#ConfiguringUsers-Importingusers) from your existing schema or [scim2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+the+SCIM+2.0+REST+APIs) endpoints to programmably import users

Answer (score 1):

I you cannot migrate user store to wso2 schema as senthalan explained then you have two options to plug custom schema.

1. Change SQL queries from **Advanced** option of secondary user store configuration
2. Writing custom user store manager by extending necessary functions like doAuthenticate, doAddUser [1]

Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION basically coming from below listener

org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener in identity.xml while handling pre authenticate event. You can even disable it.

[1]https://github.com/GayanM/custom-user-store